# Python pandas how to get the reverse of groupby

Tags: pandas, mean, pandas-groupby

I have two data frames. They are the same except for one column. I want to change the column of the second dataframe according to mean values from the first dataframe. For the latter I have to use groupby, but then I don't know how to get a reverse. Below is a minimal example, where in this particular example df_two should end up being the same as df_one. My question is how to get from tmp to df2_new - see the code below.

```
import pandas as pd


def foo(df1, df2):
    # Group by A
    groupsA_one = dict(list(df1.groupby('A', as_index=False)))
    groupsA_two = dict(list(df2.groupby('A', as_index=False)))

    for key_A in groupsA_one:
        # Group by B
        groupsB_one = dict(list(groupsA_one[key_A].groupby('B', as_index=False)))
        groupsB_two = dict(list(groupsA_two[key_A].groupby('B', as_index=False)))

        for key_B in groupsB_one:
            # Group by C
            tmp = groupsB_two[key_B].groupby('C', as_index=False)['D'].mean()   # Returns DataFrame with NaN
            tmp['D'] = groupsB_one[key_B].groupby('C', as_index=False)['D'].mean()['D']
            print tmp

    df2_new = []        # ???
    return df2_new

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A1 = {'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'B': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
          'C': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'D': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]}
    A2 = {'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'B': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
          'C': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'D': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
    df_one = pd.DataFrame(A1)
    df_two = pd.DataFrame(A2)
    foo(df_one, df_two)
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation)? This returns a dataframe with it's index aligned to the lhs dataframe

Comment: Well, I am not sure. What I do is the following: I group both dataframes, df1 and df2, first by 'A', then by 'B' and then by 'C'. At the 'C' level I calculate mean on the groups of df1 and then assign it to groups of df2. Because it's a trivial example, this mean is actually an identity, but in general it's not. I want this assignments done on groups of df2 to be also seen in the df2 or df2_new. Can pandas transform do that?

Comment: Yes I think that is what you want, it's best to add expected output so it's clearer

Comment: Expecter output is A2['D'] = A1['D'], so after the transformation df_two should be same as df_one. I am just looking at the .transform, but I don't know how to use it when I have several levels of groupby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I wanted. Please, if you find a more elegant solution I will be happy to set it as a correct answer.

Hre it is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def foo(df):
    # Group by A
    groups_a_one = dict(list(df.groupby('A', as_index=False)))

    for key_a in groups_a_one:
        # Group by B
        groups_b_one = dict(list(groups_a_one[key_a].groupby('B', as_index=False)))

        for key_b in groups_b_one:
            # Group by C
            tmp = groups_b_one[key_b].groupby('C', as_index=False).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
            df.ix[tmp.index, 'D'] = tmp['D']# assign mean values to correct lines in df

    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A1 = {'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'B': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
          'C': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'D': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]}
    A2 = {'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'B': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
          'C': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'D': [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]}
    df_one = pd.DataFrame(A1)
    df_two = pd.DataFrame(A2)
    df = pd.concat([df_one, df_two], axis=0, ignore_index=True)# To get only one DataFrame

    # run the transform
    foo(df)
```

Here is the initial state and the final one:

```
# Initial
    A  B  C  D
0   1  1  1  5
1   1  1  2  5
2   1  2  1  5
3   1  2  2  5
4   2  1  1  5
5   2  1  2  5
6   2  2  1  5
7   2  2  2  5
8   1  1  1  NaN
9   1  1  2  NaN
10  1  2  1  NaN
11  1  2  2  NaN
12  2  1  1  NaN
13  2  1  2  NaN
14  2  2  1  NaN
15  2  2  2  NaN

# Final
    A  B  C  D
0   1  1  1  5
1   1  1  2  5
2   1  2  1  5
3   1  2  2  5
4   2  1  1  5
5   2  1  2  5
6   2  2  1  5
7   2  2  2  5
8   1  1  1  5
9   1  1  2  5
10  1  2  1  5
11  1  2  2  5
12  2  1  1  5
13  2  1  2  5
14  2  2  1  5
15  2  2  2  5
```

Answer (score 8):

I think this may be simpler for certain cases:

```
groupby = dfm.groupby('variable')
for ix, row in reversed(tuple(groupby)):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Do a group by on df_one on A, B, and C and find the mean
    df_group = df_one.groupby(['A','B','C']).mean()

#Change the index
    df_two.index = [df_two['A'],df_two['B'],df_two['C']]

#Transfer the value of mean from D to 
    df_two['D'] = df_group['D']
```