# Python de-aggregate / reverse-summarize / expand a dataset

Tags: python

Is there a way to de-aggregate / reverse-summarize / expand a dataset in python? For example, if I have a dataset in the format

```
year     object     count
2020     apple        3
2020     orange       1
2021     orange       2
2021     apple        4
```

I want it to look like:

```
year    object
2020    apple
2020    apple
2020    apple
2020    orange
2021    orange
2021    orange
2021    apple
2021    apple
2021    apple
2021    apple
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804540/python-pandas-how-to-get-the-reverse-of-groupby

Comment: For this sample small dataset I have something similar to what eshirvana suggested below but the issue is my dataset is much bigger than this small example I used to illustrate the idea. I have many years and objects and manually listing all of them is not easy

Answer (score 0):

you can use`pandas` dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'year':[2020,2020, 2021,2021],
        'object':['apple','orange', 'orange','apple'],
        'count':[3, 1, 2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[['year','object']].loc[df.index.repeat(df['count'])]
print(df)
```

output:

```
>>
   year  object
0  2020   apple
1  2020   apple
2  2020   apple
3  2020  orange
4  2021  orange
5  2021  orange
6  2021   apple
7  2021   apple
8  2021   apple
9  2021   apple
```

Comment: Thanks! This certainly would work for my small dataset that I used for an example. How would I do that if I have many years of data and many objects? I certainly don't want to have to manually type all of them out?

Comment: @NadezhdaKarkelanova you don't have to do anything manually , in whichever format your dataset is (json , csv, etc) you can easily load it to pandas

Comment: you are absolutely right. I got confused. Thank you for your help!